# Get FaceVariable at GMSH Physical Line

Tags: python, differential-equations, fipy

I successfully set up a very simple diffusion problem including a source face (continuum) and sink faces (sidewall, top) on a mesh generated with GMSH.

```
from fipy import *

mesh = Gmsh2D('''Point(1) = {0, 0, 0, 1.0};
Point(2) = {12, 0, 0, 0.1};
Point(3) = {12, 16, 0, 0.1};
Point(4) = {15, 16, 0, 0.1};
Point(5) = {15, 100, 0, 1.0};
Point(6) = {0, 100, 0, 1.0};

Line(1) = {1, 2};
Line(2) = {2, 3};
Line(3) = {3, 4};
Line(4) = {4, 5};
Line(5) = {5, 6};
Line(6) = {6, 1};

Line Loop(1) = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

Plane Surface(1) = {1};

Physical Line("continuum") = {5};
Physical Line("sidewall") = {2};
Physical Line("top") = {3};

Physical Surface("domain") = {1};
''')

c = CellVariable(name='concentration', mesh=mesh, value=0.)

c.faceGrad.constrain([-0.05 * c.harmonicFaceValue], mesh.physicalFaces["sidewall"])
c.faceGrad.constrain([0.05 * c.harmonicFaceValue], mesh.physicalFaces["top"])
c.constrain(1., mesh.physicalFaces["continuum"])

dim = 1.
D = 1.
dt = 50 * dim**2 / (2 * D)
steps = 100

eq = TransientTerm() == DiffusionTerm(coeff=D)

viewer = Viewer(vars=(c, c.grad), datamin=0., datamax=1.)

for step in range(steps):
    eq.solve(var=c, dt=dt)
    viewer.plot()

TSVViewer(vars=(c, c.grad)).plot(filename="conc.tsv")

raw_input('Press any key...')
```

The calculation works as intended, however I would like to access the gradient at the physical faces I set up in GMSH. I know that I can get the gradient at faces using `c.faceGrad` and the mask representing the physical faces using `mesh.physicalFaces['sidewall']`. To get the gradient at the faces contained in the physical face, I would expect to use indexing like `c.faceGrad[mesh.physicalFaces['sidewall']]`. However, this does not yield the desired result. Is there a way to access the FaceVariable at locations specified by `physicalFaces`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that `c.faceGrad` has shape `(2, 22009)` so the mask operates on the second index as the shape of `mesh.physicalFaces['sidewall']` is `(22009,)`. So, try

`c.faceGrad[:, mesh.physicalFaces['sidewall']]`

and to access the correct shape use

`np.array(c.faceGrad[:, mesh.physicalFaces['sidewall']]).shape`

which is `(2, 160)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that solved my problem. Apparently, I did not realize that after all, the FaceVariable is just a normal ndarray that can be indexed as usual.